# Sharepoint Webservice call from a sandbox solution using custom HTTP headers

Tags: web-services, sharepoint

Been looking at this for a while and hitting quite a few dead-ends, thought I'd try here and see if the community can help.

I'm working in Sharepoint365 which is a sandboxed Sharepoint solution.

I need to access an external webservice and drag the data into sharepoint.

I've seen that you can do this from an external list which needs an external content type.
I'm trying to do this from within Sharepoint designer.

The problem I have is the webservice is a restful webservice, it doesn't come with a WSDL/asmx.

It also requires an Authentication parameter to be passed in the HTTP header. After going to the Secure Store in the administration I can see that you can set up an authentication for this.

So the problem is how do you go about getting the data in when there is no webservice definition?

Is it a case of going into Visual Studio and hand coding it?
If so is the Business Data Connection Model the right way of doing it?

Thank you.